# How to get 2 column values from single subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Here is my query: I want to get the user values which is stored in user table and comments which is stored in comments table.
The user_id is the id of the user which i fetch from comments table. 
How to get both comments with respective users how to do that with single query or there is any good and best way to do that?

```
mysql_query("select profile_pic,firstname,lastname,username,comment from user join  comments where user_no IN (select user_id,comment from comments where   question_id='".$_POST['get_comments']."') ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT profile_pic,firstname,lastname,username,comment 
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN comments ON `user`.user_no = comments.user_id
WHERE comments.question_id='".$_POST['get_comments']."'
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the join condition you didn't specify and also you didn't specify what type of join you required try this code.

```
mysql_query("select profile_pic,firstname,lastname,username,comment from user left join  comments on user.columnname=comments.columnname where user_no IN (select user_id,comment from comments where   question_id='".$_POST['get_comments']."') ");
```

The column name specifies on which column you want to join to tables.for reference please read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)